# clean lots reponse json into one dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, request, normalize

code as follows：

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

link = "http://sp.kaola.com/api/category/goods?pageSize=20&search=%7B%0A%20%20%22sortType%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%200%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22isNavigation%22%20%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%22filterTypeList%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parentCategoryId%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22categoryId%22%20%3A%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22source%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%22noStoreCount%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22isActivity%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22storeCount%22%20%3A%2060%0A%7D"
max_pages = 3
data = {}

for page_no in range(max_pages):
    try:
        req = requests.get(link + "&pageNo=" + str(page_no))
    except reqeusts.ConnectionError:
        break # Stop loop if the url was not found.

    df = req.json()
    if df["body"]["result"]["hasMore"] == 0:
        break # Page says it has no more results
    df1 = df['body']['result']
    df2 = json_normalize(df1['goodsList'])
    print df2
```

1、json_normalize is not work.but i run code one by one in my ipython is OK. why？

```
df1 = df['body']['result']
df2 = json_normalize(df1['goodsList'])
print df2
```

2、how to concat all response into one dataframe？

Comment: What does mean `json_normalize` is not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) dataframes to `list` and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

link = "http://sp.kaola.com/api/category/goods?pageSize=20&search=%7B%0A%20%20%22sortType%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%200%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22isNavigation%22%20%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%22filterTypeList%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parentCategoryId%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22categoryId%22%20%3A%204055%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22source%22%20%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%22noStoreCount%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22isActivity%22%20%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22storeCount%22%20%3A%2060%0A%7D"
max_pages = 3
data = {}

#multiple files to one df
dfs = []
#create empty df for output
d = pd.DataFrame()

for page_no in range(max_pages):
    print page_no
    try:
        req = requests.get(link + "&pageNo=" + str(page_no))
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        break # Stop loop if the url was not found.

    df = req.json()
    if df["body"]["result"]["hasMore"] == 0:
        break # Page says it has no more results
    df1 = df['body']['result']

    df2 = json_normalize(df1['goodsList'])
    #append data to list of dataframes
    dfs.append(df2)
    #concat all dataframes to one
    df = pd.concat(dfs)
    print df2

print df
```